# Global variable with innerhtml

Tags: javascript

Im executing the function with a `oninput` event trigger and the js is in a external file at the bottom of the page.

If i move the variable inside the function it works, isn't it possible to place it outside?

```js
var globalVariable = document.getElementById("div-tag").innerHTML;

function myFunc() {
    var amount = document.getElementById("txtValue").value;
    globalVariable = (amount * 0.10);
    
    console.log(globalVariable)
}
```

```html
<input id="txtValue" oninput="myFunc()">
<div id="div-tag">0</div>
```

Comment: You override your variable in your function. Or what exactly is your question?

Comment: can you add HTML as well.

Comment: Where is `oninput` being called?

Comment: Yes ofc, @Mamun

Comment: Your code seems to be working....

Comment: Which variable declaration is not working inside the function `globalVariable` or `amount`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the trick

```js
var globalVariable = document.getElementById("div-tag");

function myFunc() {
    var amount = document.getElementById("txtValue").value;
    globalVariable.innerHTML = (amount * 0.10);
}
```

```html
<input id="txtValue" oninput="myFunc()">
<div id="div-tag">0</div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mLyRQO)

Comment: Nop, that doesn't work :s it wont update the innerHTML

Comment: addded it now @Dean

Comment: It worked - my code was acutally fine - it was my gulp enviroment which made my global variables unsuable for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var globalVariable = document.getElementById("div-tag");

function myFunc() {
    var amount = document.getElementById("txtValue");
  var res =   (globalVariable.innerHTML = (amount.value * 0.10))
  console.log(res);
}
```

```html
<input id="txtValue" oninput="myFunc()">
<div id="div-tag">0</div>
```